# Awk splitting a string and comparison

Tags: awk

I have a string like `AS|REQ|XYZ|value=12` which I am splitting with:

```
awk -F\| 'print {$4}' | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
```

This gives the value 12.

But for the string `DF|REG|EXP|value=`, it comes back blank.

What I need as if my string encounters `value` in fourth column and is blank, throw error. Can this be done in awk command ?

Thanks

Comment: You could be more specific about what you mean by _throwing an error_.

Answer (score 2):

You could be more specific about what you mean by *throwing an error*. If you want the program to exit with a non-zero exit code, use `if` and `exit` with value`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{exit}'
$ echo $?
0
$ awk 'BEGIN{exit 1}'
$ echo $?
1
$ awk -F\| '{split($4,a,"="); if(a[2]=="") exit 1; else print a[2]}' foo
12
$ echo $?
1
```

or just print an error message and continue execution:

```
$ awk -F\| '{split($4,a,"="); print (a[2]==""?"ERROR":a[2])}' foo
12
ERROR
```

Test data used above:

```
$ cat foo
AS|REQ|XYZ|value=12
DF|REG|EXP|value=
```

Answer (score 2):

@JamesBrown has the right answer to your question as asked, but given the input you posted all you need to produce the output you want is:

```
awk -F'=' '{print ($NF=="" ? "Error" : $NF)}' file
```

If that's NOT all you need then edit your question to show some more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
awk -F\| '{print $4}' | awk -F"=" '{if ($2 == "") print "ERROR: Empty Value"; else print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this command might work for you. The below command will behave as expected. If you have any value in the value field, it will just print the value. Else if it is blank, it prints "error". The string was placed in test.txt

```
awk -F\| '{if($4!="value=") {gsub("value=","",$4);print $4} else print "error" }' test.txt
```

Comment: When you're writing an if-else, don't make the condition negative, make it positive. That way you don't run the risk of creating a double negative e.g. you don't end up staring at your "else" block and saying "OK, I get here when it's not true that $4 is not equal to value, so...... what does THAT mean?". Always try hard to write every condition in a positive way, in this case `if ($4=="value=") print "error"; else { other stuff }`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
cat f
AS|REQ|XYZ|value=12
AS|REQ|XYZ|value=

awk -F'[|=]' '{if($4 == "value" && $5 == "") {print ("Error Found at Line: ",NR)} else {print $0}}' f
AS|REQ|XYZ|value=12
Error Found at Line:  2
```

It search for `value` in `4th` column and `blank` in `5th` column.

Comment: So close :) You can just place both = and | inside the [], like so -F'[=|]'

Comment: @grail - Thanks for your input.